# How to speed up zxing detection?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am developing an android application in which there is a QR-code and barcode scanner. I implemented this library [ZXING](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) , but the detector works really badly.

Sometimes even in 5 minutes it is impossible to recognize the barcode. I use their functions exactly as described, although their application is working fine. What should I do? How to solve this problem?

[EDIT]
I found that if you reduce the container in which the camera is located - the result will be almost instant. The larger the container, the slower the detection. I also changed the library for [this one](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded), but it works exactly like that.

Comment: Well it is rly strange, it usually takes less then 5 seconds to recognize it. What is the quality of image and camera?

Comment: I had the same issues with this library and ended up using [this library instead](https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner). This is also based on Zxing but I found it to be quicker. I've worked with it on SDK 19+.

Comment: @MaxAves Normal. Camera takes pictures with 2304x4096 pixels. They have an application and the scanner works very fast there. I suppose that they are doing something else by passing this library.

Comment: @VladAdrian There is a way to reference their application from your app and have their application pass the result back to your app. This way is also quicker but would require your users to use a secondary application which I think is a turn off.

Comment: @Demonic218 , I have a condition: API +17. ((

Comment: @VladAdrian You could try the Barcode scanner that comes with the MLKit. The documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes) and an example app can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit). The lowest API I tested on was 19. The QR code scanner worked incredibly fast but on API 19 I couldn't read any other barcode but a QR Code.

Comment: any solution you found?

Comment: @amin, You can change the size of the frame.  The smaller the size, the higher the speed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the above problem.

> How to speed up zxing detection?

To speed up detection of barcode/qrcode just place the barcode object a bit *far* away from the `scanner/camera`. Sometimes it takes time to detect *if the barcode if too close to the camera* .

Comment: But their application works very well, even if the barcode is close to the camera.